# Delete all the folders that are older than two days from a list of folders

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have three folders. I need Ansible to check them and delete the one(s) older than two days.

Those are my tasks:

```yaml
- name: Get older files path
  find:
    paths: "{{ path }}/DB/{{ item }}/"
    age: 2d
    file_type: directory
    recurse: yes
  register: filesolderthan2
  with_items:
    - "{{ bucket }}"

- name: Remove older files
  file:
    path: item.path
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ filesolderthan2.results }}"
```

Variable file

```yaml
bucket:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
path: "/backup"
```

I did get the path but was not able to delete all those folders.
When I tried to use

```yaml
path: {{ item.path }}
```

I get dict error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files older than x days inside folder of folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178367/delete-files-older-than-x-days-inside-folder-of-folders)

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas the `register` is made under a loop, this is what the OP is actually confused with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` module will list you all the files matched in a [`files`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-files) field of a dictionary.

Since you are [registering under a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop), you have a `results` field on top of those multiple `files` field.

So, what you can do is to use a couple of [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html) filters to get all those `files`:

```yaml
- name: Remove older files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ filesolderthan2.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten(1) }}"
```